# Convert \thebibliography into BIB file, semi-automatically

Tags: biblatex, bibtex, bibliographies, conversion

I have a paper in TeX that has the \thebibliography section. I need to convert it into a BIB file.

I realize that it cannot be done automatically, but are there tools that at least partially help, with post-editing? Preferably online tools where I could paste the whole list, not pasting things one by one.

The domain is computer science and specifically natural language processing, so mathematics bibliography tools most probably will not help here.

Comment: There's [text2bib](http://text2bib.economics.utoronto.ca/), but when I last used it (nearly ten years ago), I was not impressed with the results ... though, to be fair, my needs were more complex than the tool was designed for.

Comment: See also [Convert from a textplain reference to bibtex](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/233442/35864).

Comment: Do you think your question is any different from [Convert from a textplain reference to bibtex](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/233442/35864)? If so, could you make that more explicit in your question and explain why you are not satisfied with the answers given there? If you think the two questions are essentially the same, a short heads up would be nice.

Comment: I agree, [Convert from a textplain reference to bibtex](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/233442/35864) is the same question. Perhaps `\thebibliography` only differs in `\item` instead of numbers and in the use of \it and \bf, which are absent in a plain text file.

Comment: Did you try `text2bib`? The website lists some entries that are correctly converted and some make use of `{\em ...}` as well as `\emph{...}`. The page also makes reference to `\item` as well as `\bibitem`, so I think they have you covered in most reasonable cases.

Comment: I have now voted to close this question as a duplicate as it seems to be the same question. If you feel your question was different, feel free to edit it to explain how it differs from the other question.

Comment: I agree that it essentially the same question, but I could not find the other one by its title or text. I hope this question and the comments will still be available to the users.